# Data retention (in device)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

How can I translate into German this term:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_retention

Context: **Data retention** in device (backup battery)

Datenpufferung, Datenhaltung or may be Vorratsdatenspeicherung?

Comment: As a generic term use *Datenhaltung* or *Datenspeicherung*. [*Vorratsdatenspeicherung*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorratsdatenspeicherung) is associated with monitoring the online activities, potentially in order to use these information to prosecute offense, like "Datenpiraterie" (illegal download of music, videos...).

Comment: I guess you mean Datenspeicherung, but we need to see the context to give you the right information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression I'd use for data being saved on a battery buffered memory on an external device would be:

> Durch eine Batterie-gepufferte Stromversorgung **bleiben** die Daten auf dem Gerät (dauerhaft) **gespeichert**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most "common" term would be

> [Datenvorhaltung](https://www.google.de/search?q=datenvorhaltungsregeln&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=datenvorhaltungsregeln&aqs=chrome..69i57.4321j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=datenvorhaltungs%20vorschriften)

However, it might very well be that it isn't the best choice in the very context you suggested (back up battery).